# Login my website use google api [onsignincallback not found error]

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client

I am using google api in my website to get user details from google plus api.I click signin button to login and click (permission for view profile information)accept.It's everything OK but the browser console show one error.

"Callback function named "signinCallback" not found"          cb=gapi.loaded_0:492

Return callback function not working.How to solve that problem?

My google plus api code:

```
(function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

function signinCallback(authResult) {
        alert("login success");
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
            // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style',
                    'display: none');
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                'userId' : 'me'
            });
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                var email = '';
                if(resp['emails'])
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i < resp['emails'].length; i++)
                    {
                        if(resp['emails'][i]['type'] == 'account')
                        {
                            email = resp['emails'][i]['value'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert("email ="+email);
                getUserMail(email);
                console.log('ID: ' + resp.id);
                console.log('Display Name: ' + resp.displayName);
                console.log('Image URL: ' + resp.image.url);
                console.log('Profile URL: ' + resp.url);
            });
        } else {
            alert("login unsuccessful");
            // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
            // Possible error values:
            //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
            //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
            //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    }
```

Html code:

```
<span id="signinButton">
             <span class="g-signin" 
            data-callback="signinCallback"
            data-clientid="*******.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" 
            data-scope="profile">
            </span>
    </span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly defining your Google parameters within you span element.

You should specify your Google log-in parameters as follows:

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
<meta name="google-signin-callback" content="signinCallback" />
<meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="https://schema.org/AddAction" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
<div class="g-signin"><!-- Your button here --></div>
```

See the example in the Google+ documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button-javascript) (see step 4)

Comment: No problem @nmkkannan. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I did try this code but it's show error in browser console. "Callback function named "signinCallback" not found" cb=gapi.loaded_0:439

"Callback function named "signinCallback" not found"      cb=gapi.loaded_0:439